# Unexpected end of script on button press

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a simple calculator in React Native as a first project. I have everything functioning. However, when I pressed the equals button without a number at the end I got an error, 'Unexpected end of script'. So I added a validation function to check the last input before evaluating. But I still get the error message.

Even if I just try and console log when the last character isn't a number I still get the error. I can't figure out what it is. Any thoughts? Lot's of Google searching and StackOverflow have come up empty for me. The code and the error are below.

My Code for the button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Button extends Component {
  // Validate last character is number before evaluating expression
  validateInput(data) {
    let rawData = this.props.rawData;
    let lastChar = rawData.substr(rawData.length - 1);
    lastChar !== isNaN ? this.props.newResult(eval(rawData)) : console.log(lastChar);
  }

  handleLongPress(data) {
    data === 'DEL' ? this.props.clearAll() : console.log('Not delete');
  }

  handleOnPress(data) {
    switch (data) {
      case '=':
        this.validateInput(data);
        break;
      case 'DEL':
        this.props.removeInput();
        break;
      default:
        this.props.addInput(data);
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { value, parentStyles, childStyles, text, onLongPress } = this.props
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.handleOnPress(value)}
        onLongPress={() => this.handleLongPress(value)}
        style={parentStyles}>
        <Text
          style={childStyles}
          >{text}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ rawData }) => ({
  rawData,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Button);
```

The error message:

```
Unexpected end of script

validateInput
    hashAssetFiles:100008:53
handleOnPress
    hashAssetFiles:100020:29
onPress
    hashAssetFiles:100045:40
touchableHandlePress
    hashAssetFiles:40117:45
_performSideEffectsForTransition
    hashAssetFiles:39731:34
_receiveSignal
    hashAssetFiles:39668:44
touchableHandleResponderRelease
    hashAssetFiles:39557:24
invokeGuardedCallback
    hashAssetFiles:35129:19
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
    hashAssetFiles:35151:64
executeDispatch
    hashAssetFiles:35180:128
executeDispatchesInOrder
    hashAssetFiles:35188:48
executeDispatchesAndRelease
    hashAssetFiles:35254:58
forEachAccumulated
    hashAssetFiles:35248:37
processEventQueue
    hashAssetFiles:35323:143
runEventQueueInBatch
    hashAssetFiles:35612:79
handleTopLevel
    hashAssetFiles:35617:29
<unknown>
    hashAssetFiles:35749:51
perform
    hashAssetFiles:36164:99
batchedUpdatesWithControlledComponents
    hashAssetFiles:35697:30
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent
    hashAssetFiles:35748:46
receiveTouches
    hashAssetFiles:35763:173
__callFunction
    hashAssetFiles:6616:47
<unknown>
    hashAssetFiles:6432:29
__guard
    hashAssetFiles:6587:11
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    hashAssetFiles:6431:20
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem should anyone experience something similar. Basically it was just a moment of weak brain power. `rawData` is a string. Evaluating whether the last character was a number was always going to end badly. Instead I decided to check if the last character was in an array containing the operators. Here's the change I made.

```
// Validate last character is number before evaluating expression
  validateInput(data) {
    const operators = ['*', '/', '+', '-', '%']
    let rawData = this.props.rawData;
    let lastChar = rawData.substr(rawData.length - 1);
    if (operators.includes(lastChar)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      this.props.newResult(eval(rawData));
    }
  }
```